# Android recreate fragment with custom constructor

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Is it possible to recreate fragment that depends on LiveData passed by constructor? That I can have LiveData or ViewModel with the LiveData after recreation. 
 
I have a viewPager2 that with adapter creates Fragments. The fragments need LiveData to work properly. Everything works fine until screen rotation because then android wants to recreate Fragment but with non-arg constructor so I can't get the LiveData anymore. Is there anything that will help with the problem?

Fragment

```
public class SensorFragment extends Fragment {
    private SensorViewModel viewModel;

    public static SensorFragment withSensor(LiveData<Sensor> sensor) {
        SensorViewModelFactory factory = new SensorViewModelFactory(sensor);
        SensorViewModel viewModel = factory.create(SensorViewModel.class);
        SensorFragment sensorFragment = new SensorFragment();
        sensorFragment.setViewModel(viewModel);
        return sensorFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SensorFragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
            .inflate(inflater, R.layout.sensor_fragment, container, false);

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void setViewModel(SensorViewModel viewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
}
```

ViewModel factory to create ViewModel with custom constructor

```
public class SensorViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    private LiveData<Sensor> sensor;

    public SensorViewModelFactory(LiveData<Sensor> sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new SensorViewModel(sensor);
    }
}
```

ViewPager2 Adapter that creates fragments.

```
public class SensorAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private List<LiveData<Sensor>> sensors;

    ...

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return SensorFragment.withSensor(sensors.get(position));
    }

    ...
}
```

Fragment that holds ViewPager2

```
public class ThermometerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ThermometerFragmentBinding binding =
                DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.thermometer_fragment,
            container, false);

        ThermometerViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)
            .get(ThermometerViewModel.class);
        SensorAdapter sensorAdapter = new SensorAdapter(this);
        viewModel.getThermometer().observe(this, thermometer ->
            sensorAdapter.setSensors(thermometer.getSensors()));

        binding.setAdapter(sensorAdapter);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
I've changed SensorFragment like this (and now it works)

```
public class SensorFragment extends Fragment {
    private LiveData<Sensor> sensor;

    public static SensorFragment withSensor(LiveData<Sensor> sensor) {
        SensorFragment sensorFragment = new SensorFragment();
        sensorFragment.setSensor(sensor);
        return sensorFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SensorFragmentBinding binding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(inflater, R.layout.sensor_fragment, container, false);

        SensorViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SensorViewModel.class);
        if (sensor != null)
            viewModel.setSensor(sensor);

        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    public void setSensor(LiveData<Sensor> sensor) {
        this.sensor = sensor;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no correct way to pass arguments not through _arguments_ property into fragment. So you won't be able to achieve your aim in such a way.

Comment: Moreover you construct `SensorViewModel` incorrectly, it won't outlive configuration change.

Comment: How should I construct the SensorViewModel then?

Comment: The way you create `ThermometerViewModel ` is correct, you should create `SensorViewModel ` in the same way. Am I right, that you want to access LiveData hosted in `ThermometerViewModel` from `SensorFragment `?

Comment: Yes, you are right. ViewPager2 adapter gets list of Sensors from ThermometerViewModel and passes each Sensor to SensorFragments

Comment: @art I've edited the post, do you think the way I do it now is ok?

Comment: It isn't ok again as after configuration change adapter `createFragment` method won't be called. I've posted the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204882/discussion-between-art-and-syzak).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, your Activity should create / initialize a ViewModel, and share the same ViewModel with its Fragments in ViewPager.

Example:

MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent(...)

        MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

And in your fragment:

MyFragment.java:

```
public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent(...)

        MyViewModel myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason is your ViewModel doesn't get destroyed while your Activity is recreated. All your data inside ViewModel stays as it is. It survives Orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to access one instance of viewmodel in two separate fragments of one activity. Just pass activity into to method *of* `ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())` in your fragments.

In *ThermometerFragment* and *SensorFragment* access viewmodel like that:

```
ThermometerViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())
            .get(ThermometerViewModel.class);
```

Usually the reference to the viewmodel is stored in fragment, not to livedatas. When you need to access livedata then just get it through viewmodel.